# Get value of current modal popup

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a modal that is dynamically created using a foreach. here's the example

```
 @foreach($data as $row)
    <div class="modal fade" id="tag{{ $row->employee_id }}" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="employee-salary/{{ $row->employment_id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="title" id="defaultModalLabel">Update Salary Record</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        @method('PATCH')
                        <p>Tag Salary</p>
                        {{ $row->employee_id . " " . $row->monthly_salary }}
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label>Bank Account</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="{{ $row->bank_account }}"  name="bank_account">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label>Monthly Salary</label>
                                    <input type="number" step='0.02' class="form-control" id="monthly_salary" value="{{ $row->monthly_salary }}"  name="monthly_salary">
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="button" onclick="generate()">GENERATE TAX, SSS, PAGIBIG, PHILHEALTH BRACKET</button>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label><strong>TAX</strong></label>
                                        <p>Tax Percentage: <span id="tax_percentage"></span> </p>
                                        <p>Tax Deduction: <span id="tax_deduction"></span> </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label><strong>SSS</strong></label>
                                        <p>Monthly Salary Credit: <span id="sss_monthly_credit"></span> </p>
                                        <p>ER Share: <span id="sss_er_share"></span> </p>
                                        <p>EE Share: <span id="sss_ee_share"></span> </p>
                                        <p>Total Share: <span id="sss_total_share"></span> </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label><strong>PAGIBIG</strong></label>
                                        <p>ER Share: <span id="pagibig_er_share"></span> </p>
                                        <p>EE Share: <span id="pagibig_ee_share"></span> </p>
                                        <p>Total Share: <span id="pagibig_total_share"></span> </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label><strong>PHILHEALTH</strong></label>
                                        <p>ER Share: <span id="philhealth_er_share"></span> </p>
                                        <p>EE Share: <span id="philhealth_ee_share"></span> </p>
                                        <p>Total Share: <span id="philhealth_total_share"></span> </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update Salary</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Modal is working properly without a problem, however whenever i click on the generate button the value of the current input is not being passed.

Here's the sample of the jquery I used to get the

```
function generate(){
        let monthly_salary = parseFloat($("modal .monthly_salary").val());
        let parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        let name = parent.find('.monthly_salary').val();

        let tr = $(this).closest('.modal-dialog').find('input[name="monthly_salary"]').val();
        console.log(tr);
```

I already tried using `$(this).closest('.modal-dialog').find().val()` but still have the same problem

Comment: Your input have an id. Why you don't get value by this way `$('#monthly_salary').val()`

Comment: it doesn't work. it only get the first value of the foreach not the current popup modal

Comment: oops, sorry. I don' see for loop in first line. but i have this idea. In for loop. We can create element id by combine for loop index ` @foreach($data as $id => $row)` and element name like this `id={{  @foreach($data as $row) }} . _monthly_salary` that generate id like this `1_monthly_salary`, `2_monthly_salary`. Then, onclick function now is `generate({{ $id }})`. Now you can get value by $(`${id}__monthly_salary`).val()

Comment: This sounds a good solution, I will try this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing classic issue with `this` keyword. In Your case `this` points to `window` not the clicked button. Because of this, whole of You selectors logic is broken.

To fix this problem You have 2 main solutions:

1) pass `this` as an argument:

HTML:

`<button onclick="generate(this)"> ...`

JS:

`function generate(element)`

`element` now points to the button.

2) remove `onclick` attribute from HTML and move selector to JS.

```
// add more spcificity to You selector! id/classes
$('.modal').find('button').click(function () {
    // Your current generate() function code
});
```

As a side note, I noticed You're using:

`let monthly_salary = parseFloat($("modal .monthly_salary").val());`

"modal" is missing dot in Your selector. Should be `$(".modal .monthly_salary")`. Even though, this will return first value from all modals which is probably undesirable result.

Anyway... this code:

`$(this).closest('.modal-dialog').find('input[name="monthly_salary"]').val();`

will now work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is to find the current modal, you can use the following script for finding the current modal:

```
 $("div[id^='ItemModal']").each(function () {
var currentModal = $(this);
currentModal.find('.btn-warning').click(function () {`
currentModal.find("[id*=monthly_salary]").val();
});});
```